# tsql Optimize select for aggregated fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a task to  select common addresses who have >= 3 different last names: 123 Main for my example.

I coded this in several steps, just want to learn what would be other solution, I think it can be done somehow in single step, I'm on SQL Server 2016.

This Min/Max will work for 2+ different names, but with 3+ I need do more logic  I think

```
;WITH c AS 
(
    SELECT 'Dow' LName, 'John' Fname, '123 Main' addr  
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Alexander' LName, 'Mike' Fname, '123 Main' addr  
    UNION
    SELECT 'Sam' LName, 'Kent' Fname, '123 Main' addr  
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Marth' LName,  'Rose' Fname,'123 Main' addr  
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Xavier' LName, 'Rob' Fname, '9000 Metaxa St' addr  
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Xavier' LName,  'Mary' Fname,'9000 Metaxa St' addr  
    UNION 
    SELECT '__Xavier' LName,  'Lucricia' Fname,'9000 Metaxa St' addr  
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Xclude' LName, 'John' Fname, 'Kirov 2 St' addr 
)
, --  SELECT * FROM c
c2 AS 
(
    SELECT MIN(lname) nameMin, MAX(lname) nameMax, addr, COUNT(*) cc
    FROM c
    GROUP BY addr
)
SELECT * 
FROM c2 
WHERE nameMin <> nameMax AND cc >=3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one step using `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for getting the different last names and [`HAVING()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql) for the group condition:

```
WITH c AS (
    SELECT 'Dow' LName, 'John' Fname, '123 Main' addr  UNION
    SELECT 'Alexander' LName, 'Mike' Fname, '123 Main' addr  UNION
    SELECT 'Sam' LName, 'Kent' Fname, '123 Main' addr  UNION
    SELECT 'Marth' LName,  'Rose' Fname,'123 Main' addr  UNION 
    SELECT 'Xavier' LName, 'Rob' Fname, '9000 Metaxa St' addr  UNION 
    SELECT 'Xavier' LName,  'Mary' Fname,'9000 Metaxa St' addr  UNION
    SELECT '__Xavier' LName,  'Lucricia' Fname,'9000 Metaxa St' addr  UNION 
    SELECT 'Xclude' LName, 'John' Fname, 'Kirov 2 St' addr 
)
SELECT addr, COUNT(DISTINCT LName) as LNameCount
FROM c
GROUP BY addr
HAVING COUNT(distinct LName)>=3
```

Comment: Grz Alberto, I'll just need to add one more AND to Having